# Am I doing something wrong with showing that $n\frac{X}{n}(1-\frac{X}{n})$ is an unbiased estimator for $\mathbf{Var}(X)$?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

The question is:

> If $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $\theta$, show that $n \left( \frac{X}{n} \right)\left( 1-\frac{X}{n} \right)$ is a biased estimator of the variance of $X$.

So my way to tackle this question would be:

$$ \mathbf{E}\left[ n \left( \frac{X}{n} \right)\left( 1-\frac{X}{n} \right) \right]
= \mathbf{E}\left[ X - \frac{X^2}{n} \right]
= \mathbf{E}[X] - \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{E}[X^2] $$

After that, I just plug in the given values of $\mathbf{E}[X]$ and $\mathbf{E}[X^2]$ for the binomial distribution, but my teacher say that is wrong saying that I should end up with $n \mathbf{E}[X] - \mathbf{E}[X^2]$. I don't see a way how there is another $n$? unless I'm missing something.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I see no issue with your computation. We have $$\mathbf{E}\left[n\frac{X}{n}\left(1-\frac{X}{n}\right)\right]=\mathbf{E}[X]-\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{E}[X^2]= (n-1) \theta (1 - \theta). $$

Comment: Okay. Thank you I thought I was going crazy seeing how my college professor got another n out of thin air.